# A generalization of orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrices, problem-solving

Consider the biorthogonal matrix propriety $\to$ $A^T \cdot B=I$.

How do I prove that $A \cdot B^T=I$?

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or what you tried would be a big step forward!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $A$ and $B$ are square matrices. Since [$XY=I$ iff $YX=I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852), we have
$$
A^TB=I\Rightarrow BA^T=I\Rightarrow AB^T=(BA^T)^T=I.
$$